# Repeating DIVs indipendently in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following HTML structure:

```
<div collection>
    <h2>Title</h2>
</div>

<hr>

<div collection>
    <h2>Title</h2>
</div>

<hr>

<div collection>
    <h2>Title</h2>
</div>
```

I am trying to write a function that passed an integer argument, it will clone each of those DIVs below themselves. So for example if I pass a 1, there will be no changes; with 2, there will be 2 DIVs, then other content, then 2 DIVs again, etc.

The problem is easy so far, because I can just use a jQuery selector and clone the DIVs, but it only works if the function is called once. If a second time in the future I want to call the function again, it will apply to the "new" elements as well... I have no idea how to proceed with this. Any idea?

Comment: Please include all relevant code

Comment: In order for us to comment on your jQuery code, you really need to show us... your jQuery code, so please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45455257/edit) and add it in.

Comment: Note: `collection` is not a valid attribute for [`div` elements](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-div-element). For custom data values, use [`data-*` attributes](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-*-attributes).

Comment: @PeterB: Surprisingly, in this case, we don't need the code.

Comment: Try marking new divs with some class that would indicate their nature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just give the clones an identifying feature, such as a class, and remove them prior to the operation.

Comment: I thought of that, and it does work! however it would cause a flicker because the height of the document will change for some milliseconds.

Comment: @J.Doe: So only remove the clones you won't want to keep (if the number is going down), and add any you need to make up the difference (if the number is going up).

Answer (score 0):

You can give some unique **id** or **class** to your div, then, when you copy it, don't add this unique attribute to newly created elements. This will help you to identify original element when copy will be executed for second time.

```
<div collection id="title-div">
    <h2>Title</h2>
</div>
```